# ASP.NET Core HttpxContext User is null but user is Authenticated

Tags: c#

Basically, I can log in just fine in my Client and access all pages. If I log out, I can't access anything on my client, it always redirects to my login page. Directly accessing the api endpoint is another matter. Say I call `mylocalapp.com/api/users`, directly from the browser url bar, I can still get all data. So I added `[Authorize]`. Unexpectedly, I get a 401 if I do that, DESPITE being logged in. So I checked HttpContext.User and simply User.Identity and they're empty, despite successful authentication. ClaimsIdentity is also empty. Can you identify anything that I might have done wrong? According to what I found on Google, this IS how it should be done. Thanks for your help.

Login method:
Takes user data, checks if ok, creates a JWT token and gets browser cookies (if null - session expired) then appends the token to the browser. And then logs the user in via Sign In Manager. If ok, returns ok. Context var is just for debugging purposes.

```cs
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
async public Task<IActionResult> LoginPost(AuthUser authUser)
{
    var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.Email == authUser.Email);

    if (authUser is null) return BadRequest(AppResources.NullUser);
    if (user is null) return BadRequest(AppResources.UserBadCredentials);
    else
    {
        var isPassword = _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, authUser.Password);

        if (!isPassword.Result) return BadRequest(AppResources.UserBadCredentials);

        var token = _jwtHandlerAuth.Authentication(authUser);

        if (token == null) return BadRequest(AppResources.UserAuthenticationImpossible);

        string cookieValue = Request.Cookies["jwt"];

        var returnUser = new ReturnUser
        {
            Email = user.Email,
            Name = $"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}",
            UserName = user.UserName
        };

        if (cookieValue != token)
        {
            Response.Cookies.Append("jwt", token, new CookieOptions
            {
                 HttpOnly = true,
                 IsEssential = true,
                 SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
                 Secure = true
            });
         }

         var signInResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(authUser.Email, authUser.Password, false, false);

         if (!signInResult.Succeeded) return BadRequest(AppResources.UserAuthenticationImpossible);

         var context = _signInManager.Context;

         return Ok(returnUser);
     }
}
```

My Authentication method (creates the token):

```cs
public string Authentication(AuthUser authUser)
{
      var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
      var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
      {
          Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
          {
                 new Claim("UserName", authUser.Email),
                 new Claim("Email", authUser.Email)
          }),
          Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2),
          SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
               new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(_privateKey)),
               SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
      };
      var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(tokenDescriptor.Subject);
      var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

      tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

      return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
}
```

And my Startup class services and middleware:

```cs
var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<User>();
                var identityBuilder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, builder.Services);
                identityBuilder.AddRoles<IdentityRole>();
                identityBuilder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>();
                identityBuilder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<User>>();
                identityBuilder.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    
                services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
                {
                    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
                });
    
                services.AddAuthentication(x =>
                {
                    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    x.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                }).AddCookie("Identity.Application").AddJwtBearer(x =>
                {
                    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    x.SaveToken = true;
                    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:PrivateKey").Value)),
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false
                    };
                });
    
                services.AddSingleton<IJwtHandlerAuth>(new JwtHandlerAuth(Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:PrivateKey").Value));
```

```cs
   app.UseRouting();
   app.UseAuthentication();
   app.UseAuthorization();
```

[image: Debugger on Context]

Comment: Either set your `DefaultAuthenticationScheme` to `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` or add the `AuthenticationScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` to your `AuthorizeAttribute` (`[Authorize(AuthenticationScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`)